# Split a series to several columns based on length in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a series that looks like this:

```
01 1ABCD     E    1   4.011   3.952   7.456 -0.3096  1.0132  0.2794

02 1ABCD     F    2   4.088   3.920   7.517  0.3839 -0.5482 -1.3874
```

...

I want to split it into 10 columns based on the length: the first 4 characters including spaces = column 1, the seconds 5 characters = column 2, ..., the last 8 characters = column10

The result should be something like this:

| column1 | column2 | column3 | .... | column10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 1 | ABCD | E | ..... | 0.2794 |
| 02 1 | ABCD | F | .... | -1.3874 |

How can I do this in python?

Thanks

Mehrnoosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elegant solution is to:

- Start with a list of sizes (how many chars should be in each "segment").
- Create a (compiled) Regex pattern with named capturing groups,
  each capturing a stated number of chars.
- Use *str.extract* to extract the required substrings from your *Series*.
  Group names will be used as names of output columns.

Assuming that *s* is the source *Series*, the code to do it is:

```
import re

# Define size of each group
sizes = [4, 4, 6, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
# Generate the pattern string and compile it
pat = re.compile(''.join([ f'(?P<Column{idx}>.{{{n}}})'
    for idx, n in enumerate(sizes, start=1) ]))
# Generate the result
result = s.str.extract(pat)
```

The result is:

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4   Column5   Column6   Column7   Column8  Column9  Column10
0    01 1    ABCD       E       1     4.011     3.952     7.456   -0.3096   1.0132    0.2794 
1    02 1    ABCD       F       2     4.088     3.920     7.517    0.3839  -0.5482   -1.3874
```

But note that all columns in *result* are of *object* type (actually they are strings).
So to perform any sensible processing of them, you should probably:

- strip spaces from each column (both leading and trailing),
- convert some columns to either *int* or *float*.

Comment: I also thought about *read_fwf* (e.g.) but the OP stated that he already has a *Series* with these strings.

Comment: ya, then ok. Maybe like alternative if Series is from csv shoul dbe used `pd.read_fwf`, +1